# How to configure my Notepad to use git diff

Tags: git, notepad++

I have an question to configure Notepad++: I use Notepad++ in Windows to edit my code. And when I do git diff in Linux, tous les lines show up as modified. In fact, I'm sure I opened the file but I didn't modify it in Notepad! I think it is a configuration problem of notepad, when I open a file in notepad, all the lines break are changed. So the git diff will show me that I "modified" all lines. Could you tell me how to resolve it?

Comment: So are you talking about line terminators?

Comment: Usually if all lines change it has to do with line termination: Windows' `\r\n` vs *nix's `\n`. Git has some settings that modify line endings between checkins and checkouts. Notepad++ can also replace all of one line-ending type with all of another line-ending type.

Comment: Do you share your files using Git between Windows and Linux? Or do they both access the same filesystem? What is your `git config core.autocrlf` configuration?

Comment: A plain, out-of-the-box, Notepad++ doesn't modify line breaks.  If you open a file with one type of linebreaks it will continue to use that kind when you edit the file. Are you using any language mode or extra plugins?

Comment: yes, I talk about line terminators. my git configuation core.autocrlf is true. If I try to use Edit > EOL conversion > UNIX/OSX Format, I still have the same problem.  I code in C++, I don't use extra plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the code you are editing has been committed to Git with Unix line endings (LF). Notepad++ converts line endings to CRLF, which is typically used on Windows.

You can go about solving this issue in one of two ways.

If you only intend to edit your code with Notepad++ on Windows, you can use `Edit > EOL conversion > UNIX/OSX Format` to convert all of the line endings in the edited file to the Unix format.

Otherwise, you may configure Git to checkout Unix line endings as CRLF and commit them as LF via `core.autocrlf` config option. See the excerpt from the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Fprmatting-and-Whitespace) below:

> If you’re programming on Windows and working with people who are not (or vice-versa), you’ll probably run into line-ending issues at some
>   point. This is because Windows uses both a carriage-return character
>   and a linefeed character for newlines in its files, whereas Mac and
>   Linux systems use only the linefeed character. This is a subtle but
>   incredibly annoying fact of cross-platform work; many editors on
>   Windows silently replace existing LF-style line endings with CRLF, or
>   insert both line-ending characters when the user hits the enter key.
>
> Git can handle this by auto-converting CRLF line endings into LF when
>   you add a file to the index, and vice versa when it checks out code
>   onto your filesystem. You can turn on this functionality with the
>   core.autocrlf setting. If you’re on a Windows machine, set it to true
>   – this converts LF endings into CRLF when you check out code:
>
> `$ git config --global core.autocrlf true`